# Support of Number.toString(radix)

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a list of browsers that support the `radix` argument in `Number.toString()` in Javascript. All implement `toString`, but I can't find whether they all support the `radix` argument for the `toString` function on the `Number` class.

Does anyone know what browsers support the radix argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Thomas Lahn's *ECMAScript Support Matrix*](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/#feature182) all engines support this, though some implementations fail at the tests for Range- and TypeErrors (though I think those tests are flawed).

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it in IE6 and IE7, and it works in both, so you should be safe with using it any browser.

Code: `alert((2526).toString(16));`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/cX4s3/2/embedded/result/

Also, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/k6xhc6yc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) doesn't state that the radix parameter is only available in certain versions of IE, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString), which normally lists any compatibility issues, doesn't list any.